# Is the leaking faucet a rubber gasket or other?

Tags: valve, seal

I'm trying to work out if it's the black rubber gasket that might be causing a leak or accumulation of calcium in the valve mechanism.

For context this is a faucet in an outdoor kitchen (Ramada) in my backyard in Phoenix Arizona so it's (1) subject to extreme heat for long periods and (2) very hard water. The entire unit was replaced about 5 years ago.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect us to know that. I'd start with the inexpensive o-ring. That faucet looks much older than 5 years.

Comment: What kind of leak? Is the valve body leaking or is water flowing from the tap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a combination of both. The black washer/ "o"ring looks like it's torn/shredded in parts and the actual valve has corrosion on it. You should remove the button from the top of the handle, unscrew the handle from the valve stem and just replace the stem, solving both probable causes. Finding exact washers/"o"rings are difficult unless they are in a repair kit specially made for that valev stem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the rubber gasket, it has seen better days It is cracked in multiple places so it needs to be replaced.

To clean the valve mechanism from calcium use vinegar and let it work for 10 minutes or more.

[image: gasket]